# InStr() asp classic form field validation

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to check for valid email address in a form field using:

```
if Request ("email") = "" then
        bError = true
ElseIf Instr(1, email," ") <> 0 Then
        bError = true
ElseIf InStr(1, email, "@", 1) < 2 Then
        bError = true
    else
          */go to success page*/
```

But if there is a space in the email address it still passes the validation. So my question is, how do I check for spaces using this method?

Comment: You first need to assign variable called "email" with the request value: `email = Request("email")`.

Answer (score 4):

You're better off using a regular expression for this.

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/email/how-do-i-validate-an-e-mail-address.html

```
   Function isEmailValid(email) 
        Set regEx = New RegExp 
        regEx.Pattern = "^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w{2,}$" 
        isEmailValid = regEx.Test(trim(email)) 
    End Function
```

Comment: Yes I know reg ex would be better but I cant use it in this case.

Comment: Why not? You're just passing the address to a function.

Answer (score 1):

Forget about all the elseif stuff do it simple...

```
Dim strEmail
Dim intErrors
intErrors = 0
strEmail = REQUEST("email")
strEmail = Trim(strEmail)
if strEmail = ""           then intErrors = intErrors +1;
if instr(strEmail," ") > 0 then intErrors = intErrors +1;
if instr(strEmail,".") = 0 then intErrors = intErrors +1;
if instr(strEmail,"@") < 2 then intErrors = intErrors +1;

' Put as many test conditions as you want here

if intErrors  = 0 then GotoSuccessPage
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if Request ("email") = "" or Instr(email," ") > 0 or InStr(email, "@") < 2 then
    bError = true
else
    'go to success page
    'BUT ABOUT OTHER ISSUES?

end if
```

---------------HERE IS A NON-REGEXP BASED EMAIL CHECKER, NOT SURE IF ITS FOOL PROOF BUT BETTER THAN THE SUBMITTED SNIPPET THAT SHOULD GET YOU GOING...

```
Function IsEmail(sCheckEmail)

    Dim SEmail, NAtLoc

    IsEmail = True

    SEmail = Trim(sCheckEmail)

    NAtLoc = InStr(SEmail, "@")

    If Not (nAtLoc > 1 And (InStrRev(sEmail, ".") > NAtLoc + 1)) Then

        IsEmail = False

    ElseIf InStr(nAtLoc + 1, SEmail, "@") > NAtLoc Then

        IsEmail = False

    ElseIf Mid(sEmail, NAtLoc + 1, 1) = "." Then

        IsEmail = False

    ElseIf InStr(1, Right(sEmail, 2), ".") > 0 Then

        IsEmail = False

    End If

End Function
```